# Наложение блоков помощи для незарегистрированных участников

Tags: дефект

После того как незарегистрированный участник задаёт свой первый вопрос, сверху экрана показывается плашка о завершении регистрации учётной записи:

> [image: скриншот плашки]

Также существует несколько страниц, на которых в правой части экрана показывается какой-нибудь блок помощи, например на странице редактирования вопроса показывается `Руководство по редактированию`:

> [image: скриншот блока помощи]

Так вот, эти блоки помощи позиционируются абсолютно относительно окна (то есть имеют css-свойство `position: fixed`). А так как плашка занимает некоторую высоту в верхней части экрана, то происходит наложение этих блоков помощи:

> [image: скриншот наложения]

Перенаправьте, пожалуйста, на мета мету ну или как обычно поступают с багами, общими для всех сайтов сети. Ошибка, конечно, вообще не критичная, но всё-таки. Спасибо.